# CSS height set to percent, is it relative to the parents content box, or padding box, etc

Tags: html, css

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) says:

```
The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.
```

So we have a containing block that contains a child element. The child element has `height: 100%` or some other percent.

If the containing block has height, padding, and border set, is the child elements height calculated as 100% of the containing block's content-box height, padding-box height, border-box height?

If we change the box-sizing of the container block, but also make other changes such that the container block's content-box/padding-box/border-box sizes do not change, is the size of the child element affected?

EDIT: apparently padding-box is experimental and only supported by FF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%` based size of the child is indeed calculated with respect to the size of the parent, and it does take into account `box-sizing`.

See this demo:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content-box {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box content-box">
    <div class="child">Content Box</div>
  </div>
  
  <br/>

  <div class="box border-box">
    <div class="child">Border Box</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So it seems to me that the height of a child with `height: 100%` will always be equal to the height of the parent's content area. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, it will be of the content area, not of the entire box.

Comment: Don't know why, but if you have a div of 60 pixels height and a <a> tag with height:100%, the height of <a> will be the height of all the screen, instead of 60 pixels...

Answer (score 2):

When using percent to specify the height of an element, then that percentage relates to the height of the element's *Containing Block*. Depending on some factors (see quotation below), the Containing Block may be formed by the element's parent's content edge or its padding edge. In other words, it does **not** always relate to the parent's content edge.

Changing `box-sizing` of the element's parent does not by itself influence the element's Containing Block, hence it does not change the size of the child element. However, in Khalos' code snippet the parent's content edge changes, hence the child's size changes accordingly. In that code snippet, the child's size changes *because the parent's content edge* changes, not because the parent's `box-sizing` was changed. (Am aware of comments to other answers should not appear here, but I do not have sufficiently many reputation points to comment it in the appropriate location.)

For the definition of an element's Containing Block, please see [this part of the W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details). For completeness, a quoted excerpt of that definition is given below:

> The position and size of an element's box(es) are sometimes calculated relative to a certain rectangle, called the containing block of the element. The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> 1. The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle called the initial containing block. For continuous media, it has the
>      dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is
>      the page area for paged media. The 'direction' property of the initial
>      containing block is the same as for the root element.
> 2. For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box.
> 3. If the element has 'position: fixed', the containing block is established by the viewport in the case of continuous media or the page area in the case of paged media.
> 4. If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
>    1. In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is undefined.
>    2. Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the ancestor.
>
> If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the initial containing block.
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

The answers are not complete. There are 2 cases to consider:

1. No position absolute applied to the child
2. Position absolute is applied to the child

### No position absolute applied to the child

The percentage is calculated from the **set height** of the parent. When applying box-sizing border-box, this is calculated from the set height excluding the paddings and borders of the parent. So to be more precise the height in percentage gets calculated from the content-area **only when the height of the parent is set**.

If the parent does not have a **set** height but the initial default value, which is height auto, the browser will not take a percentage of the calculated auto height of the parent. (Height auto means that the height of the element will stretch to accomodate the content which is often desirable.)

Demo:

```css
.parent1, .parent2, .parent3 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: crimson;
    margin: 10px;
}

.parent2 {
    min-height: 200px;
}

.parent3 {
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    height: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
    parent with<code>height: auto</code>
    <div class="child">
        child with <code>height: 50%</code> doesn't work
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
    parent with<br><code>min-height: 200px</code>
    <div class="child">
        child with <code>height: 50%</code> doesn't work
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent3">
    parent with<br><code>height: 200px</code>
    <div class="child">
        child with <code>height: 50%</code>. it works!
    </div>
</div>
```

### Position absolute applied to the child

When applying position absolute to the child the height in percentage always gets applied and is calculated from the height of the context, also called containing block. To establish the context the browser examines the chain of ancestors from parent to root, the first ("nearest") ancestor with position relative, absolute, fixed or sticky is used as the context. If no such ancestor is found the viewport is used as the context.

To use a parent as the context and leaving it in the normal document flow one can simply apply position relative to the parent.

```css
.parent1, .parent2, .parent3 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: crimson;
    margin: 10px;
}

.parent2 {
    position: relative;
}

.parent3 {
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    height: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.child2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
    parent with <code>height: auto</code> and no positioning.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, recusandae quis modi tenetur ut blanditiis quaerat eius nisi beatae dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, recusandae quis modi tenetur ut blanditiis quaerat eius nisi beatae dignissimos?
    <div class="child">
        child with <code>height: 50%</code> doesn't work
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
    parent with <code>height: auto</code> and  <code>position: relative</code>.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, recusandae quis modi tenetur ut blanditiis quaerat eius nisi beatae dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, recusandae quis modi tenetur ut blanditiis quaerat eius nisi beatae dignissimos?
    <div class="child child2">
        child with <code>height: 50%</code> and position: absolute. It works!
    </div>
</div>
```